# Формат значения в localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Вопрос, честно говоря, довольно глупый, но когда я заношу вот такое значение `localStorage.setItem('item', 1)`, например, на выходе получаю строку. `var a = localStorage.getItem('item')` `console.log(a)` выдает значение "1". Я могу ошибаться, но разве он не должен хранить число, а не строку в таком случае. Или, может быть, я что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, Вы ошибаетесь, он не должен, Вы делаете так.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

> Note: Name/value pairs are always stored as strings. Remember to
> convert them to another format when needed!
>
> Пары ключ/значение сохраняются как строки. Не забудьте конвертировать их в другой тип в случаях, когда это необходимо.